# Issue in connecting MS SQL server using Java program

Tags: java

I am having a problem in executing a simple select statement in Microsoft Sql Server DB using a Java program. I am facing below 2 issues,

1. Code by using statement * Resultset - program just hungs near the executequery() method and no progress after that. 
   Sample code:-(Full code pasted below)

   ```
       Statement sta = conn.createStatement();

       String Sql3 = "select name from dbo.network";
       sta.executeQuery(Sql3);
       ResultSet rs=sta.getResultSet();
   ```
2. code with preparestatment * Resultset throws error saying

> The method executeQuery() cannot take arguments on a PreparedStatement or CallableStatement

Sample Code:-

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(Sql3);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery(Sql3);
```

Complete Code:-

```
public class DbConnectionTest {


      public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException,   ClassNotFoundException {

        System.out.println("Entered into main method");
        String userName ="***";
        String password ="***";
        String url ="jdbc:sqlserver://****:1433;databaseName=***";

        try{

            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");  

        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
        System.out.println("test");
        Statement sta = conn.createStatement();

        String Sql3 = "select name from dbo.network";
        //PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(Sql3);

        //ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery(Sql3);
        sta.executeQuery(Sql3);
        //sta.getMoreResults();
        //sta.getMoreResults();
        ResultSet rs=sta.getResultSet();
        if(rs != null) 
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString("name"));
        }       
    }catch(Exception se){
          //Handle errors for JDBC
          se.printStackTrace();
    }
    }   
}
```

In Addition, I confirm the below,

1. Same query executes fine in the database.
2. SQL Browser Server service is running fine
3. TCP/IP is enabled
4. Credentials and the URL string are correct
5. sqljdbc4.jar is used.

Please help me with this issue.

Comment: It would be helpful to properly format and indent your code. Consider removing unnecessary code

Comment: I ran your code here, and it works fine doing a basic select from one of my tables.  When you say execution freezes, there's really only two reasons that would happen, your being blocked by someone / some process, or the resultset is huge (very large table).

Comment: Hi Mike, Thanks for your time. Yes I even have the same doubt but is there anything that I need to check to confirm I reach the db server without any restrictions(I mean not through the programs). Also, I confirm there is only 2 records in that table.